# Trouble defining TField programmatically

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I have some problem defining the fields of a TmemDataset.
I want to use a memDataset with some files to keep and manipulate the data for a small personal project.

here are the code snipet I use to create the fields :

```
function createField(fieldName, fieldLabel : String ; fieldType : TFieldType; 
                     group : Integer) : TField;
begin
  Result := TField.Create(nil);
  Result.FieldName := fieldName;
  Result.SetFieldType(fieldType);
  Result.FieldKind := fkData;
  if fieldLabel = '' then
    Result.DisplayLabel := fieldName
  else
    Result.DisplayLabel := fieldLabel;
  result.DataSet := memDataset;

  Result.Tag:= group;

end;
```

The call is quite simple :

```
createField('FIELDNAME', 'FieldDisplay', ftInteger, 2);
```

Unfortunately, this does not properly set the field type and compromise the whole data editing afterwards. I get a `ftUnknown` field type. How can I set the proper type for my fields ?

---

I was advised of another way of doing things :

```
procedure createField(fieldName, fieldLabel : String ;
                      fieldType : TFieldType; group : Integer);
begin
  with memDataset do
  begin
    if fieldType = ftString then
      FieldDefs.Add(fieldName, fieldType, 80, False)
    else
      if fieldType = ftWideString then
        FieldDefs.Add(fieldName, fieldType, 512, False)
      else
        FieldDefs.Add(fieldName, fieldType, 0, False);

    if fieldLabel = '' then
      FieldDefs.Items[FieldCount].DisplayName := fieldName
    else
      FieldDefs.Items[FieldCount].DisplayName := fieldLabel;

// No other way
//    medCharacter.FieldDefs.Items[FieldCount].Tag := group;
  end;        
end;
```

Except I loose some information quite important to my project : the field display name, I found a way to set, but I can't find a way to set the tag.

Comment: what happens if you use your solution but make the memdataset the owner of the Tfield rather than nil.